# binding a dgv column to objects subclass property

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using a `datagridview` to display my object collection property values to the user. The problem is that I added a subclass or nested object ( don't know exactly how to call it ) and would also like to display a property from that subclass.

**example:**

```
Public Class Person

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer
    Public Property Gender As Gender
    Public Property Adress As Adress

End Class

Public Enum Gender
    Male
    Female
End Enum

Public Class Adress
    Public Property Street As String
    Public Property City As String
    Public Property Zipcode As String
End Class
```

To add columns I don't use the auto columns option but I add them myself ( I don't want to show all properties in the dgv )

I add columns like this:

```
    Dim NameColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()

    With NameColumn 
        .DataPropertyName = "Name"
        .Name = "NAME"
        .HeaderText = "Name"
    End With

    dgvPersons.Columns.Add(NameColumn)
```

But how do I add a column that is bound to the adress class it's street property?

Comment: I've never tried but I'd guess that you might be able to use dot notation in the `DataPropertyName`, e.g. `.DataPropertyName = "Address.Street"`.

Comment: If I do that, the column is empty. But thanks for the response.

Comment: In that case, you might have to write a LINQ query to flatten your data into an anonymous type. You could omit the properties you don't want and then you wouldn't need to create the columns manually either.